# load an html file into a panel

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am new to sencha touch 2.0. I have an html file. I am trying to load this html file(or content) into a panel. I am simply using an ajax call but its not working. Following is the code.

This is the html file i am running in the browser.

**index.html**:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="touch/sencha-touch-debug.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="HTMLPanel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
```

this is **app.js**:

```
Ext.setup({
    name : 'SampleLoad',
    requires : ['HTMLPanel'],
    launch : function () {
        var HTMLPanel = new HTMLPanel({
            scroll : 'vertical',
            title : 'My HTML Panel',
            url : 'sample.html'
        });
    }
});
```

and this is **HTMLPanel.js**:

```
//HTMLPanel = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, { //gives error 
var HTMLPanel = Ext.define('HTMLPanel',{
    extend : 'Ext.Panel',
    constructor : function( config ) {
        HTMLPanel.superclass.constructor.apply(this, arguments);

        // load the html file with ajax when the item is
        // added to the parent container
        this.on(
            "activate",
            function( panel, container, index ) {
                if( this.url && (this.url.length > 0) )
                {
                    Ext.Ajax.request({
                        url : this.url,
                        method : "GET",
                        success : function( response, request ) {
                            //console.log("success -- response: "+response.responseText);
                            panel.update(response.responseText);
                        },
                        failure : function( response, request ) {
                            //console.log("failed -- response: "+response.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
            this
        )
    },

    url : null
});
```

I just want the html content to be displayed within the panel. Can someone help?

Answer (score 31):

The class system has changed quite a lot in Sencha Touch 2 compared to 1.x. It is now very similar to how ExtJS 4 is. The idea behind the changes is to make it easier to understand, quicker to develop and more dynamic.

Some changes:

- you should no longer use `new HTMLPanel({})`. Instead, use `Ext.create`, i.e. `Ext.create('HTMLPanel', {})`.
- you should no longer use `Ext.extend` to define your custom classes. Instead, use `Ext.define` with an `extend` property.
- you do not need to use `HTMLPanel.superclass.constrctor.apply(this, arguments)` anymore to call the parent. Instead, you can use `this.callParent(arguments)`
- you should very rarely override `constructor`. This is bad practise. Instead, you should use the `config` block:

  ```
  Ext.define('HTMLPanel', {
      extend: 'Ext.Panel',

      config: {
          html: 'This is the html of this panel.'
      }
  });
  ```

  Please note that configurations only go within the `config` block when you define a new class using `Ext.define`. If you are creating a new instance of a class using `Ext.create`, `new ClassName` or using an object with an xtype, configurations do *not* need to be within the config object.

You can find out more information about the new class system by reading [this guide](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/class_system). There is also a great guide on how to migrate from 1.x to 2.x [here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/upgrade_1_to_2).

So, lets make your code work.

**index.html** (nothing needs to change):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="touch/sencha-touch-debug.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="HTMLPanel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
```

**app.js**:

```
// You should use Ext.application, not Ext.setup
Ext.application({
    name: 'SampleLoad',
    requires: ['HTMLPanel'],
    launch: function () {
        var HTMLPanel = Ext.create('HTMLPanel', {
            // this is now `scrollable`, not `scroll`
            //scroll: 'vertical',
            scrollable: 'vertical',

            url: 'sample.html'
        });

        // Add the new HTMLPanel into the viewport so it is visible
        Ext.Viewport.add(HTMLPanel);
    }
});
```

**HTMLPanel.js**:

```
// You do not need to save a reference to HTMLPanel when you define your class
//var HTMLPanel = Ext.define('HTMLPanel', {
Ext.define('HTMLPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',

    // We are using Ext.Ajax, so we should require it
    requires: ['Ext.Ajax'],

    config: {
        listeners: {
            activate: 'onActivate'
        },

        // Create a new configuration called `url` so we can specify the URL
        url: null
    },

    onActivate: function(me, container) {
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            // we should use the getter for our new `url` config
            url: this.getUrl(),
            method: "GET",
            success: function(response, request) {
                // We should use the setter for the HTML config for this
                me.setHtml(response.responseText);
            },
            failure: function(response, request) {
                me.setHtml("failed -- response: " + response.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I can confirm that this is working, should be accepted answer

Answer (score 5):

`rdougan`'s answer worked for me. If it still doesn't work for you, check out [this example from the Sencha Docs](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/example/nested-list) where they're loading .js files using AJAX a slightly different way (it would be exactly the same for .html files). To get the source, [download the Sencha Touch 2 SDK](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/download/) and it will be under `examples/nestedlist`.